# Links de âncora abrem uma função JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo uma página HTML simples com links para âncoras espalhadas pelo documento, porém depois de incluir uma galeria de imagens em jQuery, os links passaram a abrir a galeria ao invés de rolar para a âncora. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Eis a chamada do método:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#gallery').gallerie();
        });
    </script>
```

Exemplo de um link e uma âncora utilizados:

```
    <li><a href="#empresa">EMPRESA</a></li> 

    <div class="row" id="empresa">
```

Comment: Pode incluir um exemplo na pergunta dos links e das âncoras?

Comment: Adicionados À descrição

Comment: Se vc retirar `$('#gallery').gallerie();` as âncoras funcionam normal?

Comment: Sim... porém ela serve para chamar a função que abre as imagens em uma galeria. No entanto, os linsk das Âncoras estão chamando essa função das imagens ao invés de setar para a âncora.

Answer (score 1):

Olhando a [documentação do plugin](https://github.com/patiek/gallerie), por padrão, ele irá pegar todas as tags `<a>` como âncora da galeria. O que você deve fazer é colocar uma classe em cada tag `<a>` da galeria, por exemplo, `class="gallerie-image"`:

```
<div id="gallery">
   <a class="gallerie-image" href="imagem1.jpg"><img src="miniatura1.jpg"/></a>
   <a class="gallerie-image" href="imagem2.jpg"><img src="miniatura2.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

E iniciar o plugin alterando a opção `elem` apontando para a classe:

```
$('#gallery').gallerie({
   elem: 'a.gallerie-image'
});
```

Assim o plugin só irá buscar as tags `<a>` da galeria, não alterando o comportamento normal das outras tags `<a>` da página.